# Parent/Child relation in search engine index (Rails 3.2 and ElasticSearch >v1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am using the official gems suite of elasticsearch [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails), I am having really hard time trying to index a parent/child relation, and I am not sure whether my problems are in the mapping or the indexing or the querying or in all of them !! so I wont post my code snippets.

Is there a full working example of the following:

- Mapping of both the child and parent indices
- Indexing/Updating/Deleting of both child and parent
- Querying an advanced query, on both indices; meaning that I need to search on the parent index with 'has_child' query, also need to search on the child index with 'has_parent' query and filter.

I found a [full example](https://gist.github.com/demirhanaydin/6548883) using 'Tire' gem, and I copied a lot of it but still no luck and can't find the equivilant methods in elasticsearch-rails gem, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [test](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/test/integration/active_record_associations_parent_child.rb) inside the gem, which has exactly what I needed and It works !

Posting it if someone has the same issue.